# OpenCV: Can't convert from "double" to "_Tp" due to possible loss of data

Tags: c++, image, opencv, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a function, that does some calculations on a pixel.

```
void someCalc(Mat& img) {
  double min, max;
  minMaxLoc(img, &min, &max);

  double conRangeMin = 100;
  double conRangeMax = 150;

  for (int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++) {
      Vec3b& pixel = img.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));
      pixel[0] = (pixel[0] - conRangeMin) * ((max - min) / (conRangeMax - conRangeMin));
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting following errors/warnings:

- The program crashes with the  error code "-1073740940" and I noticed that if I remove the adress operator for the `pixel` variable, the error disappears.
- And I am getting the error `Can't convert from "double" to "_Tp"...` at the same line I get the first error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error code -1073740940 (hex 0xC0000374) means heap corruption occurred. Also, the 1st error is a runtime error, whereas the 2nd error is a compile-time error, so you can't possibly be getting both errors at the same time.

Comment: Why are you calling the [`Point` overload of `img.at()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a23cd599a27c59bae64b0c40ad645ea49) instead of calling the [`(int,int)` overload](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac40425b84f60b39fd35e03814122661f)? And how are you initializing the `img` before passing it to `someCalc()`?

Comment: I am not getting both errors at the same time. When I remove the address operator, I get the second error, otherwise the first. @RemyLebeau all I am doing is to make sure the Image is grey `cv::cvtColor(img, img_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`. And also tried calling the `int, int` overload. This time I get the -1073741819 error.

Comment: Based on the [`Mat` class documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html), I think you need to swap the `x` and `y` values when calling `img.at()` (and then consider renaming them with more meaningful names), eg: `img.at<Vec3b>(Point(y, x))` or `img.at<Vec3b>(y, x)`

Comment: "all I am doing is to make sure the Image is grey " -- `img.at<Vec3b>` assumes a 3channel img. if your img has only one (grayscale) you need `img.at<uchar>` instead

Comment: documentation is not clear on the meaning of passing a Point to at(). it could very well be correct to use Point(x,y) -- Vec3b means the type is byte/uint8. the compiler is justified in complaining about a type issue (loss of precision potentially). consider an explicit cast. -- the issue is *not* pixel being Vec3b because its first element is accessed by `pixel[0]`

Comment: It worked with `double pixel = processed.at<double>(x, y);` And it actually worked without the address-operator, so the pixels are actually changing as expected. Can someone explain why. Am I not just changing the local variable with this: `double pixel = processed.at<double>(x, y);` and  `pixel = [here the calc]` and not the actual pixels of the image? It still doesn't work WITH the address-operator, so `double& pixel = processed.at<double>(x, y);`